# How to activate JMX on my JVM for access with jconsole?

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring, jmx, jconsole

How to activate JMX on a JVM for access with jconsole?

Comment: it is allowd, and actually it is only a reminder for me, because I always forget where to copy the parameters from and now I know where I find it :-)

Comment: Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: More than once I have searched SO for something and found a question answered... by myself. And one of those was asked by me as well. This is why it is good to put your own answers in. Also, think of all the other people that may have encountered your problem, if you answer your question you will be helping them too.

Comment: Updated doc for Java 8 is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html)

Comment: @Mauren: Can you provide a reference to your closed question you answered yourself?  It might be worth discussing on Meta.

Comment: @kevinarpe I'm sorry. This has been a long time ago and I'm no longer able to provide you with the link and content.

Comment: Question should mention you may have the exact same problem when jvisualvm tells you "Failed to create JMX connection to target application" when trying to start CPU sampling.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

The relevant documentation can be found here:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Start your program with following parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

For instance like this:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -jar Notepad.jar
```

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false` is not necessarily required
but without it, it doesn't work on Ubuntu. The error would be something like
this:

```
01 Oct 2008 2:16:22 PM sun.rmi.transport. customer .TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop
WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=37278] throws
java.io.IOException: The server sockets created using the LocalRMIServerSocketFactory only accept connections from clients running on the host where the RMI remote objects have been exported.
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:89)
    at sun.rmi.transport. customer .TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
    at sun.rmi.transport. customer .TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672

**Also be careful with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`** which
makes access available for anyone, but if you only use it to track the JVM on
your local machine it doesn't matter.

**Update**:

In some cases I was not able to reach the server. This was then fixed if I set this parameter as well: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1`

Comment: The -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false is needed on Centos now as well

Comment: Nit pick: It's weird to me that `com.sun.management.jmxremote` has the default value as `true`.  (Thank you Sun!)  To be super clear, especially to those less familiar with JMX nobs, I use: `com.sun.management.jmxremote=true` Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Comment: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname" worked like a charm for me !

Comment: Was using Ubuntu 14.04 and everything worked out-of-the-box. Moved to Debian jessie and I had to do everything explained in this answer

Comment: setting the hostname to localhost is very important if you are trying to connect a to a remote server through SSH tunnel, which is a very common case.

Comment: That works only if I disable the firewall on the server. I opened the port 9010/tcp in this example of course, I also tried to add `Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9011` and open in firewall - still cant connect with the firewall being up. Any thoughts? Have I missed anything?

Comment: @Carmageddon `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=[...]` in combination with `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[...]` should work. Without those both I ran into similar issues, so make sure that your configured port for `.rmi.port` is really accessible by your client AND the same for the configured `.hostname`! Without the latter explicitly defined, Java will assume some IP it things is the primary interface of the server, which might still be blocked in your firewall. Without the port it assumes some random one. You might use Wireshark or Process Monitor to debug connections of client/server.

Comment: `java.rmi.server.hostname`
The value of this property represents the host name string that should be associated with remote stubs for locally created remote objects, in order to allow clients to invoke methods on the remote object. The default value of this property is the IP address of the local host, in "dotted-quad" format. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html

Comment: In case you already have access to the server using ssh, you don't need to mess with the firewall, just create a bridge: `ssh -g -L <local-port-in-your-machine-to-map>:localhost:<remote-server-jmx-port> <linux-username>@<remote-server-ip>`. Example: `ssh -g -L 9523:localhost:9523 my-linux-account@5.23.56.78` then go to the `jvisualvm` and add a JMX connection as `localhost:9523`. Don't forget to add: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1` in your remote server, because without it, it won't work.

Answer (score 81):

Running in a Docker container introduced a whole slew of additional problems for connecting so hopefully this helps someone.  I ended up needed to add the following options which I'll explain below:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${DOCKER_HOST_IP}
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9998
```

**DOCKER_HOST_IP**

Unlike using jconsole locally, you have to advertise a different IP than you'll probably see from within the container.  You'll need to replace `${DOCKER_HOST_IP}` with the externally resolvable IP (DNS Name) of your Docker host.

**JMX Remote & RMI Ports**

It looks like JMX also requires access to a remote management interface ([jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html)) that [uses a different port](https://johnpfield.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/how-to-monitor-a-remote-jvm-running-on-rhel/) to transfer some data when arbitrating the connection.  I didn't see anywhere immediately obvious in `jconsole` to set this value.  In the linked article the process was:

- Try and connect from `jconsole` with logging enabled
- Fail
- Figure out which port `jconsole` attempted to use
- Use `iptables`/`firewall` rules as necessary to allow that port to connect

While that works, it's certainly not an automatable solution.  I opted for an upgrade from jconsole to [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/index.html) since it let's you to explicitly specify the port on which `jstatd` is running.  In VisualVM, add a New Remote Host and update it with values that correlate to the ones specified above:

[image: Add Remote Host]

Then right-click the new Remote Host Connection and `Add JMX Connection...`

[image: Add JMX Connection]

Don't forget to check the checkbox for `Do not require SSL connection`. Hopefully, that should allow you to connect.

Comment: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=[...]` is as well the key in case of tunnelling JMX/RMI through SSH. Without those, remote objects are accessed using the public/main/... IP of the server using some random port, which can't be forwarded easily.

Comment: I can confirm that you really need to use the external to container IP. For example it doesn't work with `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0`

Comment: I didn't need to use `DOCKER_HOST_IP` anywhere - I just used `localhost` and forwarded the ports when running the docker image: `-p 9998:9998, -p 9999:9999` etc.

Comment: This also worked for my Docker-Java-Setup. It would be easier to mention that the `jstatd` port is equivalent to the  `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` parameter. It is not explicitly stated, but it would improve the quality of your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Note, Java 6 in the latest incarnation allows for jconsole to attach itself to a running process even after it has been started without JMX incantations.

If that is available to you, also consider jvisualvm as it provides a wealth of information on running processes, including a profiler.

Comment: This only works if you are running jconsole on the same host as the JVM you are trying to monitor.

Comment: @ Thorbjorn If i start my java program without any parameters and try to connect with jconsole, I see in my program in the list but when I try to connect it fails. I think it is because of lack of SSL certificates. I just wanted to see the demo hence I had to use the parameters specified in the answer by user3013578 and it worked for me (JDK 1.7 , Windows 8.1, 64 bit).

Comment: The attach API requires jconsole to have the same 32/64 bit JVM as the launched program on some platforms.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using WAS ND 7.0

My JVM need all the following arguments to be monitored in JConsole

```
    -Djavax.management.builder.initial= 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8855 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: Yes your answer worked for me (JDK 1.7, windows 8.1 64 bit)

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, I used the following params:

```
-Djavax.management.builder.initial= 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

and also I edited `/etc/hosts` so that the hostname resolves to the host address (192.168.0.x) rather than the loopback address (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 4):

along with below command line parameters ,

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Sometimes in the linux servers , imx connection doesn't get succeeded. that is because , in cloud linux host, in /etc/hosts so that the hostname resolves to the host address.

the best way to fix it is, ping the particular linux server from other machine in network and use that host IP address in the

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP address that obtained when you ping that linux server.
```

But never rely on the ipaddress that you get from linux server using ifconfig.me. the ip that you get there is masked one which is present in the host file.

Answer (score 4):

The below options works for me:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname={host name}
```

and remember to open 9010 port in the server

```
sudo ufw allow 9010/udp
sudo ufw allow 9010/tcp
sudo ufw reload
```

Answer (score 2):

Run your java application with the following command line parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8855
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

It is important to use the **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false** parameter if you don't want to setup digital certificates on the jmx host.

If you started your application on a machine having IP address *192.168.0.1*, open **jconsole**, put **192.168.0.1:8855** in the *Remote Process* field, and click *Connect*.

Comment: What is the expected behavior if you forget `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`? Should `jconsole` show an error, or would it just quietly fail to connect?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Run the application using following parameters.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Above arguments bind the application to the port 9999.

**Step 2:** Launch jconsole by executing the command jconsole in command prompt or terminal.

Select ‘Remote Process:’ and enter the url as {IP_Address}:9999 and click on Connect button to connect to the remote application.

You can refer this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2018/07/jmx-expose-resource-for-remote.html) for complete application.

Answer (score 2):

**RUN LOCAL PROCESS JCONSOLE using Remote Process option**

To run locally, this worked for me -

I added this in my *vm* args -

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6001
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6001
```

- I opened **JConsole** via **Intellij** Terminal
- It was showing me all PID's in grey in local
- So I selected remote process and logged in using host - localhost:6001
- Keep empty username & password
- Then click connect

---

- Make sure no other process is running on port 6001. You can also use other ports.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if your java process is already running with JMX parameters. Do this:

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

Check your java process you need to monitor. If you can see jmx rmi parameter **Djmx.rmi.registry.port=xxxx** then use the port mentioned here in your java visualvm to connect it remotely under jmx connection.

If it's not running through jmx rmi port then you need to run your java process with below mentioned parameters :

```
-Djmx.rmi.registry.port=1234 -Djmx.rmi.port=1235 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Note: port numbers are based on your choice.

Now you can use this port for jmx coneection. Here it is port `1234`.

Comment: Should you be able to see the port 1234 in use by jmx once you run this? `sudo lsof -i:1234` is not showing anything for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, and [created a GitHub project for testing and figuring out the correct settings](https://github.com/cstroe/java-jmx-in-docker-sample-app).

It contains a working `Dockerfile` with supporting scripts, and a simple `docker-compose.yml` for quick testing.