# How can I connect to Weblogic remotely using JConsole?

Tags: weblogic, jmx, jconsole

Which URL, port and weblogic server side settings do I need to use?

Comment: On weblogic10.3.4 (maybe other versions as well), you MUST use the weblogic console's username/password for authentication EVEN IF you've added the java start argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false (!!!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends if you want to connect to a WebLogic MBean server (Domain, Runtime, Edit) or platform (JDK) MBean server (See [MBean Servers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jmx/understandWLS.html#wp1127769)).

Connecting with JConsole to a **WebLogic MBean server** is usually a real pain:

1. Enable Anonymous Admin Lookup if version is lower than 10.3 (See [WebLogic anonymous user permissioning](http://blog.inflinx.com/2008/08/26/weblogic-anonymoususer-permissioning/))
2. Enable IIOP Protocol for Admin Server and Application Servers (See [Enable and configure IIOP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/channels/EnableAndConfigureIIOP.html))
3. Launch jconsole with a custom commandline (See [Managing WebLogic servers with JConsole](http://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/managing_weblogic_servers_with))

Connecting to **platform MBean server** is like any other JVM (See [How to activate JMX on my JVM for access with jconsole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole/856882#856882)), but you would not see any WebLogic MBeans unless you configure WebLogic to use it (See [Registering MBeans in the JVM Platform MBean Server](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jmxinst/designapp.html#wp1089583)).

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your server start-up parameters.  Change the port (7011) to whatever you prefer.  You should be able to use JConsole then by specifying the remote server "{host}:{port}"

Note: the {host} does not include a "http://" prefix.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7011
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Also, you probably don't want to disable authentication like this in a production environment, but the parameters above should help you with testing.  When using this, you won't need to specify a username/password in JConsole.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to enable the remote server to listen on a specific port for JMX -http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html#remote

URL would be your server's listen address. You also have the option to require authentication to limit the usage of the debug port.

Comment: This doesn't work. Have you actually got this working with weblogic?

Comment: Yes. Can you include more details on the version of WebLogic and Java you are using as well as the startup parameters?