# How to activate JMX on my JROCKIT JVM for access with jconsole?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, jmx, jconsole

How to activate JMX on my JROCKIT JVM for access with jconsole?

(somewhat a follow up question to [How to activate JMX on my JVM for access with jconsole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole))

The main reason I ask is, because I get strange errors if I try to run jboss (6.0.0.Final) with activated JMX, and jboss doesn't start correctly. So maybe it is a jboss problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, and at the same time support a variety of potential networking configuration challenges, as well as work with any JVM (most ?) is to install a [JMXConnectorServer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorServer.html) in the JBoss App Server. Now you're using standard J2SE connectivity.

Older builds of JBoss 6 had this support built in and I'm not sure why jboss removed it but here's how you can recreate it.

1. Find the jar [jboss-as-jbossas-jmx-remoting.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jbossas-jmx-remoting.jar.zip) which has a maven signature of **org.jboss.jbossas** / **jboss-as-jbossas-jmx-remoting**. Copy it to the **[jboss-home]/server/[your-server]/lib** directory.
2. Create a file like jmx-connector-service.xml as outlined below and drop it into your **[jboss-home]/server/[your-server]/deploy** directory.
   [image]

(Sorry, was having trouble formatting XML for stackoverflow).

When the server starts, you will see a log statement like this, pretty early on:

**INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://10.213.14.95/jndi/rmi://10.213.14.95:1090/jmxconnector**

You can tweak the bindings, the use of a registry, the ports etc, but now you can open JConsole and connect to **service:jmx:rmi://10.213.14.95/jndi/rmi://10.213.14.95:1090/jmxconnector**.

You can find more information on the service [here](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/jboss/mx/remoting/service/JMXConnectorServerService.html).