# How can I obtain the system properties for a particular JVM instance programmatically?

Tags: java, properties, jvm

I wish to obtain the system properties set for a third party java process/JVM. I need to do this programmatically. For example getting the "java.class.path" property. How can I do this?

I know we can get properties for a java program that we write using System.getProperty(). But I need to get the system properties for a third-party JVM. How can I obtain the same?

Comment: What do you mean by third-party JVM? Are you referring to a JVM on which you can't run your code?

Comment: Just ask the program running in third party JVM for info

Comment: Yes, I mean..I cannot run my java code on that JVM. Alternately, is it possible to connect to a particular JVM and run your java code on it?

Comment: Sumit, could you elaborate what you mean by asking the program running in third party JVM for info?

Answer (score 21):

If by third-party JVM you just mean another JVM then you should try *jinfo*. This will not work with all JVM implementations, but most probably have it or something similar. *jinfo* takes a process id as argument (or remote system, see *man jinfo*). To find the process id use *jps* or *jps -v*.

```
jinfo 74949
Attaching to process ID 74949, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.4-b02-402
Java System Properties:

java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path = /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries
java.vm.version = 20.4-b02-402
awt.nativeDoubleBuffering = true
...
```

Comment: Thanks Roger!!! That would be the output I'm looking for :)
But the jinfo <PID> command does not run on my JVM implementation. It asks for a specific flag and does not dump all Java System Properties as hoped. I am using Java 1.6.0.29 implementation on a Windows box. Is there another way out?

Comment: The documentation indicates that it should work the same on windows. Have you tried jinfo -flags <PID> or jinfo -sysprops <PID>?

Comment: I did try both options..But sadly, it throws this message back at me :(



Usage:
    jinfo <option> <pid>
       (to connect to a running process)

where <option> is one of:
    -flag <name>         to print the value of the named VM flag
    -flag [+|-]<name>    to enable or disable the named VM flag
    -flag <name>=<value> to set the named VM flag to the given value
    -h | -help           to print this help message

Comment: I tried 1.6.0_30 (from Oracle) on a Windows XP, and the jinfo there supports both -flags and -sysprops. Are you using a non Oracle JVM? Are you sure you are not using an jinfo from an older JVM?

Comment: This is a weird situation. I use 1.6.0.29 jinfo from Oracle on Windows XP. I really appreciate all the help extended even though the solution seems to evade me. I will try alternative approaches, if possible, and let you know if i succeed.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

**Starting from Java 7**, you can use the command `jcmd` **that is part of the JDK** such that it will work the same way on all OS.

It can work with both a pid or the main class.

## With the pid of the target JVM

The syntax is then `jcmd ${pid} VM.system_properties`

**Example:**

```
> jcmd 2125 VM.system_properties
2125:
#Tue Jul 24 18:05:39 CEST 2018
sun.desktop=windows
...
```

## With the class name

The syntax is then `jcmd ${class-name} VM.system_properties`

**Example:**

```
> jcmd com.mycompany.MyProgram VM.system_properties
2125:
#Tue Jul 24 18:05:39 CEST 2018
sun.desktop=windows
...
```

More details about [how to use `jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jcmd.html).

See also [the `jcmd` Utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html)

Comment: I didn't know about this tool. Nice!

Comment: This helped me a ton today, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To programetically access the remote JVM statistics (JVM system parameters, Thread statististics, Memomy information, GC Information and other information), [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javamanagement-140525.html%20JMX) can be used. For that, remote JVM must allow JMX connection ([Check this on how to activate JMX in remote JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole%20Check%20this)). Basically you need following -D parameters to be set in the remote JVM with appropriate values:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

Once the above setting is done, connect to the JMX port and get different Mbean information from the remote server from your application: Following is some sample code:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection mbeanServerConnection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

With this `mbeanServerConnection`, you can access different managed beans and get the required information from the MX beans. For system properties, you need to get the `RuntimeMXBean` bean and invoke `getSystemProperties()` to get all system parameters.