# JMX custom mapping

Tags: java, jmx, mxbean

I understand that within the realm of JMX you have an `MXBean`, which is using only open types specified within Java. there are mappings between standard types and open types of course.

Now, I know you can extend those with your own custom types by providing your own mappings... What is the point of that? Does that not kill the purpose of using one common set of types, which is basically the definition of the `MXBean` in the first place?

Comment: I don't quite understand.  What "custom types" are you talking about?  Jconsole needs to have all of the classes beforehand so if you return an unknown class from a get method, it will be shown as unavailable on the client.  If you are talking about writing your own JMX client then you can certainly remote custom classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MXBean, or more specifically, [OpenType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/OpenType.html)s, allow you to supply a definition of a "complex" class broken down into its constituent components defined in supported standard types. For example, and this is drawn from this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939335/java-mxbean-custom-types/14940922#14940922), consider a JMS supporting class implementing this interface:

```
public interface JmsDestinationAttributesMBean {
    public String getName();
    public int getMessagesCurrentCount();
    public int getConsumersCurrentCount();
}
```

Normally, JConsole wouldn't know what to do with this, but when exposed by an MXBean, it will render it as a **String** and two **ints**, along with some meta-data to describe what those values are.

[image]

See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html) for more in depth coverage.