# How to return custom object in a MBean interface

Tags: java, jmx

I have create a custom JavaBean I want to return from my MBean method. The following is the custom JavaBean:

```
package org.text.jmx;

public class Person {
 private firstName;
 private lastName;

 public Person(){
 }

 public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }

 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }

 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

The MBean interface is the following:

```
package org.text.jmx;

public interface TestJmxMBean {
 public Person getPerson();
 public void setPerson(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

The class the implements the MBean:

```
package org.text.jmx;

public class TestJmx implements TestJmxMBean {
 private Person person = new Person();

 public Person getPerson() {
  return person;
 }

 public void setPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
  person.setFirstName(firstName);
  person.setLastName(lastName);
 }
}
```

I create a server application that registers the above MBean, which is successful. I create a client application which successfully connects to the server application via JMX, but when I call the testJmx.getPerson() method from the client application is receive an error that it can't return the Person object. What am I doing wrong? It works fine is I just define the return type as as String or String[] from the TestJmx.getPerson().

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939335/java-mxbean-custom-types

Answer (score 0):

In order to expose a custom object as a JMX attribute, or the return value or an operation, it must be defined as an [OpenType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/OpenType.html). The usual way of doing this is to define an [MXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html). I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939335/java-mxbean-custom-types) which should give you an idea on how to proceed.