# maven/visualvm: how can i use visualvm to profile a running surefire process?

Tags: java, maven, visualvm, jvisualvm

I can attach to the surefire process, but trying to profile it shows for sampling:

```
CPU sampling:
Not available. Failed to create JMX connection to target application. Use 'Add JMX Connection' action to attach to the application.

Memory sampling:
Not available. Failed to read objects in target application. Check the logfile for details (use Help | About | Logfile).
```

And trying to start profiling shows an empty error message box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says "failed to create JMX connection" what about enabling jmx when starting maven?
Here is a question [how to activate jmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole) and i think you can use MAVEN_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS to provide those parameters to maven.