# Remote Accessing MBeans deployed on JBoss AS 7.1.3

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I have deployed MBeans in JBoss AS 7.1.3. updated standalone.xml for management connector interfaces. The document http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?tag=jconsole says to add systems-propeties org.apache.tomcat.util.ENABLE_MODELER to enable remote access. But start up fails if we update this property.

I am struck accessing MBeans remotely. Any help much appreciated

Comment: This is old but what parameters were you trying?  I assume you saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole

Comment: Could you provide the parts of your standalone.xml you changed and the log output on startup and/or deployment of your mbean?