# Jconsole does not shows my process in list

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

For jconsole is the PID also required the JMX management and port?
As per my understanding, if we want to connect through port then only JMX agent is required.

My java process is not running with jmx port.  When I execute Jconsole , I only get the jconsole in the local process list, nothing else.

I am running jconsole and my process both by SYSTEM account.

Comment: Can you show us what arguments you are using to start the JVM you want to connect to?

Comment: On your local box, you should be able to see all JVM instances running.  However, you need to make sure that each process is configured for JMX.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole

Comment: No..my process is not started with JMX port opened.But my question is if i want to doing jconsol with PID,then i dont think JMX port enabling is required..