# How to generate a cpu snapshot in production?

Tags: java, profiling

With VisualVM, I can attach to a local java process, start/stop CPU profiling, and generate a snapshot. I don't even need to instrument the process with any special agents etc.

Is it possible to do the same thing on a headless production server? I know I can configure the process to attach the debugger remotely, but I want to minimize the amount and impact of changing the customer environment. I just want to run a command to profile for a while and generate a snapshot file, which I can scp to my workstation for analysis with VisualVM or equivalent.

Preferably, the whatever program I run to do this should be freely redistributable, so that I can bundle it with my Java app and have it be available in the customer environment.

Ideally, just like with VisualVM, I'd like to be able to attach to a running system without a restart.

The closest I've found so far is instrumenting with [hprof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html):

```
  java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,interval=20,depth=3 classname
```

but that requires a restart to start profiling and another to stop, as I don't see a way to turn sampling on and off at runtime.

Is there a better way? If there's no out-of-the-box solution, how would one build it? It must be possible since VisualVM does it.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need a debugging connection, you only need a JMX connection. But maybe that’s what you meant.

To recall, when you run your application with the appropriate options like

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

(replace the latter two if you need secure transport) you can just connect with `JVisualVM` from another machine with GUI using the “Add JMX connection” and `servername:9876` as the address.

Details are given in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html
and http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html

---

When you are using `JVisualVM` to connect to a local JVM, the only difference is that it will detect local applications and tell them to load the JMX agent if it is not already running.

So you can write a small local command line application to be executed on the server and connect to the JVM and start the JMX agent. Once the JMX agent is started you can connect with `JVisualVM` remotely. [The program in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19400008/2711488) shows how to do this.

It uses the [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html) to locate the JVM and tell it to load the JMX agent and opens the JMX connection. The second step can be omitted if you will open the JMX connection using `JVisualVM` remotely.

Alternatively you can extend this program to a command line sampling tool using the opened JMX connection. [The first example code of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912148/2711488) gives an idea of how to implement a sampler. It samples its own JVM but since it uses the `ThreadMXBean` you can change it to work for remote connections as well easily.

Answer (score 0):

have you ever try yourkit java profiler ?
it does lots of thing for performance
but it also show cpu usage and ....

you can use it to snapshot cpu and show it in your production
from below link you can find documents and also download it:

http://yourkit.com/features/index.jsp#cpu_compare_snapshots

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I want to know how to capture a CPU snapshot in a headless environment. Does YourKit have a command-line mode?

Comment: I will answer since this question is about YourKit profiler. Yes, YouKit has command-line tool to control profiling http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/command_line_tool.jsp You do not need YourKit GUI to start/stop profiling and capture snapshots. And you do not need GUI to integrate Java EE server with profiler agent. There is command-line Java EE integration wizard http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/profiling_j2ee_remote.jsp

Comment: The biggest problem with yourkit is their licensing.  YourKit could run in standalone agent mode with provided capture configuration, but as the environment is an production of another customer who don't own YourKit license, do you are allowed to use there  yourkit agent to generate profiling snapshot (i.e. does the agent is license free and the YourKit GUI under license)?  If agent is under license, then yourkit is useless for profiling remote customer application, where headless mode is required.