# Why am I getting the error "connection refused" with JMX

Tags: java, networking, jmx

I am unable to connect to JMX object. Here is how I create a JMX object:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    try {
        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.javasimon.jmx.example:type=Simon");
        if (mbs.isRegistered(name)) {
            mbs.unregisterMBean(name);
        }
        SimonManagerMXBean simonManagerMXBean = new SimonManagerMXBeanImpl(SimonManager.manager());
        mbs.registerMBean(simonManagerMXBean, name);
        System.out.println("SimonManagerMXBean registerd under name: "+name);

    } catch (JMException e) {
        System.out.println("SimonManagerMXBean registration failed!\n"+e);
    }

    while (true) {
        // waiting for connections
    }
}
```

This is a code for connecting to the remote JMX object:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1:9999/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
SimonManagerMXBean simonManagerMXBean = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbsc, new ObjectName("org.javasimon.jmx.example:type=Simon"), SimonManagerMXBean.class);
return simonManagerMXBean;
```

Unfortunatelly I receive the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
    at my.code.RemoteSimonManagerFactoryImpl.createSimonManager(RemoteSimonManagerFactoryImpl.java:24)
    at my.code.Demo.main(DemoAggregation.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:101)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:255)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:97)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 19 more
```

If I try to connect to my JMX server (as to local process) using "jconsole" utility, I first get "ConnectionFailedSSL1" error, but when I click "Insecure" button in the error form, I connect successfully.

Both server and client are on the same computer.

I am using Windows 7 x64. Windows firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:

Most likely you are not running your server with the right JVM parameters.  Jconsole uses a different mechanism to find and to connect to local processes.  Your client code is trying to use TCP/IP to connect to your server.  To turn this on you'll need to add something like the following to your Java command line on your server:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

See: [How to activate JMX on my JVM for access with jconsole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole/856882#856882)

As an aside, you might want to consider using my [`SimpleJMX` library](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) which does all this code for you.  It includes a JMX client code as well.

Comment: Do I need to add this settings on client side or on server side?

Comment: The first line reads "not running your server with the right JVM parameters" @IvanMushketyk.

Comment: It works. Thank you. The correct port number is 1099.

Answer (score 4):

I've manage run Tomcat with JMX (Tomcat 8, Windows) by:

1. add 
   `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`
2. run with admin permissions

Comment: These parameters works also on `Ubuntu 20.04` + `Tomcat9`

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error. In my case I was using a @PostConstruct annotation and that method was attempting to use the RMI connection before Spring had a chance to configure the connection.

It didn't end up being anything wrong with the configuration of the connection, just that I accidentally tried to use it before it was ready. Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

check your tomcat's bin folder for catalina.sh file. open it up and find java server parameters. add thoose followings to $JAVA_OPTS on any line you want.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

you are done!