# VisualVM unable to connect remote tomcat in docker with RMI

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, visualvm

I am runing tomcat in a docker container on a remote machine. Now I want to use VisualVM to  connect. My docker start command:

```
docker run -d --name tomcat -p 26000:8080 -p 9090:9090 -p 9091:9091 -v /data/docker/tomcat/webapps:/data/tomcat/webapps -v /data/docker/tomcat/logs:/data/tomcat/logs -e CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"  my.private.hub/tomcat:latest
```

And the catalina.log:

```
13-Mar-2015 10:29:56.615 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
13-Mar-2015 10:29:56.666 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
13-Mar-2015 10:29:56.718 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
13-Mar-2015 10:29:56.718 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.787 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.20.0
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.13.0-40-generic
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_76-b13
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /data/tomcat
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /data/tomcat
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2048M
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048M
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/data/tomcat/endorsed
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/data/tomcat
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/data/tomcat
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tomcat/temp
13-Mar-2015 10:31:01.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.5.1.
```

But VisuamVM is unable to connect:

```
'Cannot connect using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.0.119:9090/jmxrmi'
```

where 192.168.0.119 is the address of the remote host machine.

Answer (score 0):

this

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1

should use your docker host machine ip that you use for your connection to it

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.119

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812609/1099452) ([also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32523713/1099452)) but no way.

At the end I could connect using a [SSH tunnel](http://maythesource.com/2013/12/04/connecting-to-jmx-from-visualvm-using-ssh-tunnel/).