# How do I attach VisualVM to a simple Java process running in a Docker container

Tags: java, docker, jmx

Actually I wanted a solution working for JEE containers, specifically for Glassfish, but after I tried many combinations of settings and did not succeed, I reduced the setup to the simplest possible case.

Here is my Hello World daemon started in a Docker container. I want to attach `jconsole` or `VisulaVM` to it. Everything is on the same machine.

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

Building: `docker build -t hello-world-daemon .`

Running: `docker run -it --rm --name hwd hello-world-daemon`

Questions:

- what JVM parameters should be added to `CMD` command line?
- what ports should be exposed and published?
- what network mode should Docker container be using?

I do not show my failed attempts here so that correct answers will not be biased. This should be a pretty common problem, yet I could not find a working solution.

**Update. Worked solution**

This Dockerfile works

```
FROM java:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", "Main"]
EXPOSE 9010
```

in combination with the docker run command

```
docker run -it --rm --name hwd -p 9010:9010 hello-world-daemon
```

`VisualVM` connects via right click *Local->Add JMX Connection*, and then entering `localhost:9010`, or through adding a remote host.

`JConsole` connects via selecting a *Remote process* with `localhost:9010`.

When defining the connection as remote, any interface listed by `ifconfig` can be used. For instance, `docker0` interface with address `172.17.0.1` works. The container's address `172.17.0.2` works too.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

At first you should run you application with these JVM params:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then you should expose port for docker:

```
EXPOSE 9010
```

Also specify port binding with docker run command:

```
docker run -p 9010:9010 -it --rm --name hwd hello-world-daemon
```

After that you can connect with Jconsole to local 9010 port and manage application run in Docker.

Comment: Nope.. VisualVM: `Cannot connect to localhost:9010 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9010/jmxrmi`. Jconsole: `Connection failed: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

Comment: why do you expose same port twice?

Comment: Connect not to localhost, to your network interface.

Comment: You expose docker port to port on your network interface.

Comment: To which interface? If I connect on `docker0` interface `172.17.0.1`, or on `wlan1` interface `192.168.0.103`, I get *Connection faild: Connection refused*

Comment: Understood. So, when run container specify this bind with -p 9010:9010 option and all will be fine.

Comment: Here's my command line `docker run -it --rm --name hwd -p 9010:9010 hello-world-daemon`

The java process: `root      4398  2673  0 03:09 pts/29   00:00:00 java Main -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`

Does not work

Comment: Add this option --bind 127.0.0.1 and try to connect to localhost.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Docker run does not have such option.

Comment: It worked finally. My mistake was that I appended JVM options after the `Main` class name in the command line. All `-D` options were silently ignored by `java`.

Comment: Same applies when using `-jar`. For some reason the `-Dcom.sun.management` parameters must be passed before the `-jar` option. Weird in my eyes.

Comment: @EthanLeroy any arguments after `-jar foo.jar` are sent to the main function of the main class (defined as `Main-Class` in the JAR manifest); basically, arguments before `-jar` are for the JVM, arguments after `-jar` are for the program that's being run

Comment: Beware: both `jmxremote.rmi.port` AND `jmxremote.port` need to be set.

Comment: I was also missing `=true` for `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` as suggests [this article](https://technicaldifficulties.io/2017/12/19/connecting-visualvm-to-a-local-docker-container-from-scratch).

Answer (score 17):

I followed [an other SO response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32523713/535203) and it worked.

I started my Java process inside the container by adding those JVM params:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port> \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<port> \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_HOSTNAME
```

and started the Docker container specifying `-e HOST_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME -p <port>` to the `docker run` command.

Then I've been able to access to this remote Java app from my local JVisualVm by adding a remote JMX connection ("File" > "Add a JMX Connection...") and specifying `<dockerhostname>:<port>` in the "Connection" input, and checking "Do not require SSL connection".

Comment: What is `$HOST_HOSTNAME` exactly? Is it host of machine running docker or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is the hostname of the host running docker. It can be the result of the `hostname` command, so you could pass it to docker while launching your container like this: `-e HOST_HOSTNAME=\`hostname\``

Comment: Thank you, `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` was the missing part for me

Answer (score 17):

FWIW, this is how I was able to attach VisualVM to a Java process inside a Docker container running on macOS:

Main.java:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Hello ");
            System.out.println("world");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.2-slim
COPY Main.class /
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["java", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010", \
"-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost", \
"Main"]
```

Compile the Java code, build the image and run the container like this:

```
$ javac Main.java
$ docker build -t main .
$ docker run -p 9010:9010 -it main
```

Then attach VisualVM using JMX to localhost:9010

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me, and giving the example Dockerfile made it easy.

Comment: thank you for the example of DockerFile,this example save my life

Answer (score 7):

You can also use docker-compose to set up your container. Steps:

Create your image (Dockerfile)

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
```

Build your image

```
docker build -t app .
```

Create a tag

```
docker tag app:latest app:staging
```

Set up your docker-compose

```
app:
    image: app:staging
    ports:
      - 8050:8050
      - 8051:8051
    volumes:
      - ./target/app.jar:/usr/src/myapp/app.jar
    entrypoint:
      - java 
      - -Dspring.profiles.active=local 
      - -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      - -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8051
      - -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
      - -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      - -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      - -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8051
      - -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
      - -jar 
      - ./app.jar
```

Port 8050 is the one I am using to run the JVM and the 8051 makes the remote connection. I have tested using VisualVM to see if I can connect to the JVM inside the container and it worked. You just need to Add a JMX connection:

[image: Add Jmx connection]

Then it will appear the process:

[image: Jvm running inside docker]

Answer (score 4):

As answered by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383822/3959535).
I had to use the `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` java option on my Windows machine.

Just be sure not to use the CMD in JSON format in your Dockerfile as this doesn't support shell expansion.

Dockerfile example:

```
FROM java:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
#Do not use CMD in JSON format here because shell expansion doesn't work in JSON format
#Shell expansion is needed for the ${HOST} variable.
CMD java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${HOST} \
Main
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all of you for routing me to the right direction. Finally I got it working in more complex config: Kubernetes via Docker Desktop under Windows 10 on local machine.

My app's config:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=30491
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=30491
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

Pod's port:

```
ports:
- name: jmx
  containerPort: 30491
  protocol: TCP
```

Service's port:

```
ports:
- name: jmx
  nodePort: 30491
  port: 9010
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: jmx
```

Answer (score 2):

To all of you that still suffer from an error like the below:

[image]

In my case it was that i used in my Docker YML different port mappings for the ports:

e.g:

```
15100:9090
```

but apparently in your port bindings you must assign **the SAME port for external port and internal port** !

Reference:
https://forums.docker.com/t/exposing-mapped-jmx-ports-from-multiple-containers/5287/5

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this issue since Dec 2019? Or does it still persist?