# Monitor java application inside docker using JConsole

Tags: java, linux, docker, jmx, jconsole

I'm trying to monitor java app, running inside docker container using JConsole, but getting an error:

> Connection failed: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested
>   exception is java.net.SocketException;

I'm using next docker params from [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108868/how-do-i-attach-visualvm-to-a-simple-java-process-running-in-a-docker-container#answer-35108974)  (also used diff extra flags from comments, like: Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.16.114.98 + --net=host, )

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9010:9010 --rm -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" gateway
```

OS: Red Hat 7

Here is the output from `docker inspect`:

```
[
{
    "Id": "06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942",
    "Created": "2017-08-18T12:52:37.002174333Z",
    "Path": "/bin/sh",
    "Args": [
        "-c",
        "echo \"The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...\" \u0026\u0026     sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} \u0026\u0026     java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 22543,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2017-08-18T12:52:38.539827439Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "760fc9348dddb4ef6a3a031e6c75d31645ac811ce17a27289e462f265d21d5e7",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942/06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942-json.log",
    "Name": "/desperate_hugle",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ],
            "9010/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "9010"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "VolumeDriver": ""
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "devicemapper",
        "Data": {
            "DeviceId": "574",
            "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-135637248-06df0e186f49297e217bab77c9101926bc2333c429d4551a151a64159a82c942",
            "DeviceSize": "107374182400"
        }
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "42e8ebbf5846da5067567cab9a72e75931c1190b94a5d62169b9c2cf54e33138",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/42e8ebbf5846da5067567cab9a72e75931c1190b94a5d62169b9c2cf54e33138/_data",
            "Destination": "/tmp",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "06df0e186f49",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "5701/udp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {},
            "9010/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre",
            "JAVA_VERSION=8u131",
            "JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.131.11-r1",
            "JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "echo \"The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...\" \u0026\u0026     sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} \u0026\u0026     java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war"
        ],
        "Image": "gateway",
        "Volumes": {
            "/tmp": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "1a318dd2e3bffc03a0242b08ba4e8a6592f076f89f317da8ba825f2be7ca01d5",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "5701/udp": null,
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ],
            "9010/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "9010"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/1a318dd2e3bf",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "df67c23d6e56d645dfe6a8767598bacd35d86e1b29a4caf078fd4c0bc5a92784",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "EndpointID": "df67c23d6e56d645dfe6a8767598bacd35d86e1b29a4caf078fd4c0bc5a92784",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,

            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the value of the java.rmi.server.hostname property.

This needs to be the hostname or IP address that is used by the JMX client to connect to your JVM. If you try to connect using 127.0.0.1:9010 then use -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 on startup

Comment: after I've added this flag `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1` I still have the same error.

Comment: Were you  able to find a solution, I am having same issue.