# Is there any way to attach VisualVM to java lambda function runned by AWS SAM local

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

There is a way to run lambda function locally using:

```
sam local start_lambda [OPTIONS]
```

The function is written in Java. I want to investigate memory allocation.
Therefore I need to attach VisualVM to java process running within docker container started by SAM CLI.

There is a way to expose JMX for java running within docker: [How do I attach VisualVM to a simple Java process running in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108868/how-do-i-attach-visualvm-to-a-simple-java-process-running-in-a-docker-container)

The question is how to pass the above configuration when running SAM local?