# How to run multiple JVM params in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parameters, jvm

I got this list of JVM params from the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35108974/7809534:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

And I would like to run them in docker-compose.

This is what I tried:

```
environment:
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010"
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

But it is not working.

How can I do it?

Comment: multiple JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS are overriding each other so you have to combine them all in one single entry, separated by spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to find a solution.

Here it is:

```
environment:
    - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: OMG, I had tried like 20 other options until I found your answer, which is the only one that worked. I still don't get why the normal YAML multiline value does not work, like the one in the other answer here. I needed it for Tomcat's JAVA_OPTS, but it seems to work in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Use YAML multiline string operator '>' to merge the lines

```
environment:
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: >
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: This was not working for me, but it was pretty close to the working solution