# Do i need to activate JMX to connect local app with jconsole?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I have my web application running on java 8, which i need to connect through jconsole . I am able to connect jconsole without any change(i am not sure
if i did any change in the past) but my collegue is not able to connect through jconsole

We both are running java application separately on our windows machine with separate jconsole on same box.

So my question in general is do we need to do any configuration/setting to monitor java application/process from jconsole on same machine or remote machine?

Comment: You both try to access to a local application right? Do you use the jconsole corresponding to the version of Java used by the application launched locally?

Comment: `You both try to access to a local application right?` Yes`Do you use the jconsole corresponding to the version of Java used by the application launched locally?` Yes. Do i need to make any explicit setting/config to monitor even local application ?

Comment: I don't believe so as you try to access to a local application, have you tried with jvisualvm?

Comment: Have a look in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole

Comment: Are using "java -jar <jconsole jar name>" or "jconsole. exe"? If it is the second approach, try with the first one?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes i can connect with jvisualVm also. So per your understanding JMX setting are only required to monitor remote app . For local app no explicit setting are required. Is that correct ?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu i have seen that link but it does not say anywhere whether these settings are required only for connecting to remove jvm ?

Comment: Yes we used to have to add the System property `com.sun.management.jmxremote` but it is not more needed since Java 6, read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Comment: What about your colleague, can he access to his application with JVisualVM?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i need to check with him. As of now he tried with jconsole only

Comment: Does your colleage see the desired process in the list in the New Connection dialog, or in visualvm in the list under Local? If not, does he run the application with TMP set to a directory where his id (and thus JVM) can create a subdirectory and files?