# Profile performance of JMeter when running running as a remote server

Tags: jmeter, visualvm

When running JMeter on my desktop, I can use VisualVM to monitor the characteristics of JMeter as I perform load tests.

JMeter VisualVM
[image]

However, when I set up JMeter on a remote server and have jstatd running, I do not see my application under that server.  I can see jstatd running, with the following command:

```
root@jmeter:~# netstat -nlp | grep jstatd
tcp6       0      0 :::39337                :::*                    LISTEN      8410/jstatd     
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN      8410/jstatd
```

Has anyone been successful in getting this set up?  I can blindly increase the JVM properties, but I would like to see how my jmeter tests perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jstatd description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstatd.html)

> Monitors Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) and enables remote monitoring tools to attach to JVMs. This command is **experimental and unsupported**.

I would suggest switching to the same "jvisualvm" approach, but connecting to JMeter instance remotely, not locally, as per [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) guide.

1. Add the following lines to *system.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   java.rmi.server.hostname=remote_machine_IP_here   
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.host=remote_machine_IP_here
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=remote_machine_PORT_here
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.portremote_machine_PORT_here
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
   com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up. (Alternative way of setting Java System properties is passing them via -D arguments to JMeter startup script like:

   ```
   jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.10.10.10 .....
   ```
3. In jvisualvm -> Remote -> Add Remote Host put a connection string like:

   - `remote_machine_IP:remote_machine_PORT`
     or
   - `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://remote_machine_IP:remote_machine_PORT/jmxrmi`

Alternatively you can use [PerfMon](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) plugin which collects a way more detailed statistics and able to plot it via the relevant JMeter Listener. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for more details on setting up and using PerfMon with JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps mentioned here, using jstatd:

[Remote Monitoring VisualVM using jstatd](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/visualvm-monitoring-remote-jvm-over-ssh-jmx-or-not/)

As an alternative, you can try with JMX:

[enable remote monitoring using JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole)