# Accessing remote Spring Boot via JMX with VisualVM

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmx, visualvm

I need to monitor Heap allocation and usage of a Spring Boot remote application using VisualVM. I cannot change the code, but I've seen it done locally, so the configurations in source code must be correct. I need to be able to expose JMX ports. Currently, I have this in the application's configuration

```
RUN_ARGS="--spring.profiles.active=dev -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT>
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<PORT> 
  -Djava.server.hostname=<IP>"
```

where both instances of `<PORT>` are the same, and indentation is added for reading purposes only, nonexistent in the file itself.
In VisualVM, then, I try creating a Remote and adding a JMX Connection to it. I tried both syntaxes, `<hostname>:<port>` and `service:jmx:<protocol>:<sap>`, but none seem to work.

EDIT: I'm doing this inside the RUN_ARGS variable used in Spring Boot's configuration file. I don't know if it needs to be in another variable, such as JAVA_OPTS

EDIT 2: Checking netstat, I found that the port is there as LISTEN... Now I can't connect from my machine. I'm using this https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/visualvm-monitoring-remote-jvm-over-ssh-jmx-or-not/

EDIT 3: I found I can telnet to the port, but VisualVM still refuses it...

Comment: You say to connect remotely. Have you checked that there is no firewall in between, which blocks the ports?

Comment: I just checked and neither firewalld or iptables is up.

Comment: Are you able to telnet <remote server> <port> from your machine?

Comment: I think you need to pass just the below in VM arguments:                                     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false      Check the answer for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole

Comment: I am not able to telnet the port, but I already thought so. I am simply unable to expose the ports. Gonna try your solution now.

Comment: I tried to do it with java -jar directly, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the port that you are trying to use free on that server?

Comment: Yes, it is. I even tried changing ports, but no luck

Comment: Checking netstat, I found that the port is there as LISTEN... Now I can't connect from my machine. I'm using this https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/visualvm-monitoring-remote-jvm-over-ssh-jmx-or-not/

Comment: I found I can telnet to the port, but VisualVM still refuses it...

Comment: Did you find a solution?..