# How can I parse a tomcat status page without flooding access logs?

Tags: tomcat, get

For a project that I am currently embarking on, I am looking to read in text from a bunch of status pages of applications that are running within tomcat.

What I am trying to do is create a conglomerated status page that will show the status of the tomcat application (online/offline).

Up until now I've created a script that will parse the status pages of the applications and format the results into a table and then write the results to an html file; thus, creating a status page for all of my applications.

I've come to realize that every time I refresh the page, I am sending more and more GET requests to these sites and thus flooding the access logs of the tomcat applications.

What I'm looking for help with is a work around to parsing these status pages without spamming GET requests... OR, a way of disabling the GET flooding in the access logs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell how the status pages are created. But you could also get the applications states by querying [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html). Once [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole), you can get *live* data form your VMs. Using JMX's [MBeans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/index.html) (which already exist for Tomcat) you could create a status page showing your applications on a single page, without parsing the former status pages and writing them to a database.

To check wether this is an opportunity, you can just start your server and open Java Mission Control (`jmc.exe` in your JDK's `bin` folder) and connect, by clicking `MBean Server` below the right process. Then in the `MBean Browser` (tab at the bottom) you will find something like `Catalina` or `Tomcat` (according to your Tomcats service name). In a subfolder, there is a type called `WebModule`, showing your installed applications. It should look like this:

[image]

You can query this data at any time, to create your own status page (i.e. in a controller).

Comment: You can even create your own application MBeans and register them with the local MBean server. Same output method. See [Monitoring Apache Tomcat with JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/presentations.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of may ways you can do this, like using SNMP

another easy way is to create a read only status page, which indicate if the service is up or not.

like that,

```
worker.list=jk-watch
worker.jk-watch.type=status
worker.jk-watch.read_only=true
worker.jk-watch.mount=/user/status/jk
worker.list=jk-manage
worker.jk-manage.type=status
worker.jk-manage.mount=/admin/status/jk
```